# How to Load Custom Spring Configuration Before CassandraDataAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am running a Spring Boot application connecting to a Cassandra database with Spring Data.  The Spring Data connection relies on username and password that will be generated by a custom Configuration Class, but the application won't start because it loads `CassandraDataAutoConfiguration` before ever getting to the custom Configuration Class, causing the application to fail with an authentication error.  I need to make sure that this custom Configuration class is loaded before `CassandraDataAutoConfiguration`.

I have tried adding `@AutoConfigureBefore({CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class})` to the custom Configuration class, but am still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to configure the order in which beans are instantiated by spring you can use:

```
@DependsOn("A") 
 public class B {
 ...    
}
```

This would create bean "A", than "B".

[Reference](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/using-depends-on.html)

Comment: In this case I want my custom Configuration to load before CassandraDataAutoConfiguration, which is provided by Spring boot, so I can't add the "DependsOn" to this class.  Is there some way to do it the other way around?

Comment: Ahh, then you can use @Primary annotation to give your bean a precedence. You can also use @Order([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)) to define the creation order for your beans.

Comment: I wasn't able to put the "DependsOn" directly in my configuration class, but I put it in the Service class that the CrudRepository was injected into and this fixed the problem, since it ensured my custom configuration class was loaded before the Repository class.  Thanks!